# Wavelink - .get_player всегда принимает значение none

Tags: python

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
import wavelink
from disnake import FFmpegPCMAudio
import re

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=disnake.Intents.all(), help_command=None)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    node: wavelink.Node = wavelink.Node(uri='lavalink.lexnet.cc:443', password='lexn3tl@val!nk', secure=True)
    await wavelink.NodePool.connect(client=bot, nodes=[node])
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.command()
async def playg(ctx: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction):
    voice_channel = await bot.fetch_channel(1054742915500482563)
    vc = await voice_channel.connect()

    node = wavelink.NodePool.get_node()
    player = node.get_player(ctx.guild.id)

    track = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search("fdgsdfgddslfsdl;fsdjlk fdslkgjdfkl;gklfdjkgjdfbvlkxvnsdlfds, dslfkjsmd fjs dmjfs", return_first=True)
    await player.play(track)

bot.run('')
```

Не знаю почему, но переменная `player` всегда принимает значение None, хотя бот получает правильное id сервера дискорд. Так же пользователь уже находиться в голосовом канале при использовании команды поэтому трек и не проигрывается, по крайней мере я так полагаю.

Comment: `print(node.players)` что выдаёт?

Comment: Выдаёт `{}` - пустой словарь.